VS Code stopped working with micro-pico extension on all three of my computers and all three Pico W s at same time
all was great until last PM.  Programmed in AM with easy modifications of controlling led s , very elementary and all was fine. I ran a couple of old programs and they worked fine before I put the MAC to 'sleep.'    Later went to turn back on and nothing in terms of MicroPython on VSCode worked.(I did not even unplug the pico when I left for a couple hours.   When I try to "configure"on VSCode  a MicroPython picoW, the bottom line of the editor spins "activating extension" but nothing happens.  This occurred  on all three of my MNACs and all three of my Picos.  Did not change settings on MAC or in VS Code. My microcontrollers work fine with Thony IDE still.   Wondering if there was an auto update of VS Code or what?   I heard there was a way to use an older version of VS Code.  The only recent update I saw on line of vs code was in July 2024.
